# Need Clickmap on webpage

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want a clickmap on a webpage. I m getting X & Y co-ordinates of click event, all the click events co-ordinates are storing in database. But i want a small "dot" image on each X & Y co-ordinates.   Plz help....how to get "dot" on each user click event.
I m using jQuery, PHP, MY SQL.
Thanks in advane.

Comment: _I m using jQuery, PHP, MY SQL_. Can you show what you tried so far?

Comment: i got x& y co-ordinates from pagex and pagey function in jquery. then for all the click events on that webpage m storing in my sql database. please check http://sharayuj.comlu.com/3.php, all the clicks on this page link, will get on http://sharayuj.comlu.com/4.php. but i want clickmap on 3.php.....I hope you will understand. i m new in development. just wanted to get   strong in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add DIV, if you know position CSS:

```
 div.dot{position:absolute;width:1px;height:1px;background:#cc0000;}
```

(red background)

and JS:

```
$('body').append('<div class="dot" style="top:'+calculated_top_position+'px ; left:'+calculated_left_position+'px;"></div>');
```